# How to get glass break effect with text

Tags: css

I am searching for a script that creates a glass break effect with text using CSS but I didn't find anything.

I used this but

```js
// triangulation using https://github.com/ironwallaby/delaunay

// For more check out zachsaucier.com

const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;

var images = [],
  imageIndex = 0;

var image,
  imageWidth = 50,
  imageHeight = 50;

var vertices = [],
  indices = [],
  prevfrag = [],
  fragments = [];

var margin = 50;

var container = document.getElementById('container');

var clickPosition = [imageWidth * 0.5, imageHeight * 0.5];

window.onload = function() {
  TweenMax.set(container, {
    perspective: 500
  });

  // images from http://www.hdwallpapers.in
  var urls = [
      'http://i.imgur.com/QddsEpk.jpg',
      'http://i.imgur.com/OeDykaH.jpg',
      'http://i.imgur.com/lLHspCj.jpg',
      'http://i.imgur.com/tCz9GQS.jpg'
    ],
    image,
    loaded = 0;
  // very quick and dirty hack to load and display the first image asap
  images[0] = image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    if (++loaded === 1) {

      for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        images[i] = image = new Image();

        image.src = urls[i];
      }
      placeImage();
    }
  };
  image.src = urls[0];
};

function placeImage(transitionIn) {
  image = images[imageIndex];

  if (++imageIndex === images.length) imageIndex = 0;

  var num = Math.random();
  if (num < .25) {
    image.direction = "left";
  } else if (num < .5) {
    image.direction = "top";
  } else if (num < .75) {
    image.direction = "bottom";
  } else {
    image.direction = "right";
  }

  container.appendChild(image);
  image.style.opacity = 0;

  if (transitionIn !== false) {
    triangulateIn();
  }
}

function triangulateIn(event) {
  var box = image.getBoundingClientRect(),
    top = box.top,
    left = box.left;

  if (image.direction == "left") {
    clickPosition[0] = 0;
    clickPosition[1] = imageHeight / 2;
  } else if (image.direction == "top") {
    clickPosition[0] = imageWidth / 2;
    clickPosition[1] = 0;
  } else if (image.direction == "bottom") {
    clickPosition[0] = imageWidth / 2;
    clickPosition[1] = imageHeight;
  } else if (image.direction == "right") {
    clickPosition[0] = imageWidth;
    clickPosition[1] = imageHeight / 2;
  }


  triangulate();
  build();
}

function triangulate() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    x = -margin + Math.random() * (imageWidth + margin * 2);
    y = -margin + Math.random() * (imageHeight + margin * 2);
    vertices.push([x, y]);
  }
  vertices.push([0, 0]);
  vertices.push([imageWidth, 0]);
  vertices.push([imageWidth, imageHeight]);
  vertices.push([0, imageHeight]);

  vertices.forEach(function(v) {
    v[0] = clamp(v[0], 0, imageWidth);
    v[1] = clamp(v[1], 0, imageHeight);
  });

  indices = Delaunay.triangulate(vertices);
}

function build() {
  var p0, p1, p2,
    fragment;

  var tl0 = new TimelineMax({
    onComplete: buildCompleteHandler
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 3) {
    p0 = vertices[indices[i + 0]];
    p1 = vertices[indices[i + 1]];
    p2 = vertices[indices[i + 2]];

    fragment = new Fragment(p0, p1, p2);

    var dx = fragment.centroid[0] - clickPosition[0],
      dy = fragment.centroid[1] - clickPosition[1],
      d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
      rx = 30 * sign(dy),
      ry = 90 * -sign(dx),
      delay = d * 0.003 * randomRange(0.9, 1.1);
    fragment.canvas.style.zIndex = Math.floor(d).toString();

    var tl1 = new TimelineMax();

    if (image.direction == "left") {
      rx = Math.abs(rx);
      ry = 0;
    } else if (image.direction == "top") {
      rx = 0;
      ry = Math.abs(ry);
    } else if (image.direction == "bottom") {
      rx = 0;
      ry = -Math.abs(ry);
    } else if (image.direction == "right") {
      rx = -Math.abs(rx);
      ry = 0;
    }

    tl1.from(fragment.canvas, 1, {
      z: -50,
      rotationX: rx,
      rotationY: ry,
      scaleX: 0,
      scaleY: 0,
      ease: Cubic.easeIn
    });
    tl1.from(fragment.canvas, 0.4, {
      alpha: 0
    }, 0.6);

    tl0.insert(tl1, delay);

    fragments.push(fragment);
    container.appendChild(fragment.canvas);
  }
}

function buildCompleteHandler() {
  // add pooling?
  image.style.opacity = 1;
  image.addEventListener('transitionend', function catchTrans() {
    fragments.forEach(function(f) {
      container.removeChild(f.canvas);
    });

    fragments.length = 0;
    vertices.length = 0;
    indices.length = 0;

    placeImage();
    this.removeEventListener('transitionend', catchTrans, false);
  }, false);

}

//////////////
// MATH UTILS
//////////////

function randomRange(min, max) {
  return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}

function clamp(x, min, max) {
  return x < min ? min : (x > max ? max : x);
}

function sign(x) {
    return x < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  } < script >

  //////////////
  // FRAGMENT
  //////////////

  Fragment = function(v0, v1, v2) {
    this.v0 = v0;
    this.v1 = v1;
    this.v2 = v2;

    this.computeBoundingBox();
    this.computeCentroid();
    this.createCanvas();
    this.clip();
  };
Fragment.prototype = {
  computeBoundingBox: function() {
    var xMin = Math.min(this.v0[0], this.v1[0], this.v2[0]),
      xMax = Math.max(this.v0[0], this.v1[0], this.v2[0]),
      yMin = Math.min(this.v0[1], this.v1[1], this.v2[1]),
      yMax = Math.max(this.v0[1], this.v1[1], this.v2[1]);

    this.box = {
      x: Math.round(xMin),
      y: Math.round(yMin),
      w: Math.round(xMax - xMin),
      h: Math.round(yMax - yMin)
    };

  },
  computeCentroid: function() {
    var x = (this.v0[0] + this.v1[0] + this.v2[0]) / 3,
      y = (this.v0[1] + this.v1[1] + this.v2[1]) / 3;

    this.centroid = [x, y];
  },
  createCanvas: function() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = this.box.w;
    this.canvas.height = this.box.h;
    this.canvas.style.width = this.box.w + 'px';
    this.canvas.style.height = this.box.h + 'px';
    this.canvas.style.left = this.box.x + 'px';
    this.canvas.style.top = this.box.y + 'px';
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  },
  clip: function() {
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.translate(-this.box.x, -this.box.y);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.v0[0], this.v0[1]);
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.v1[0], this.v1[1]);
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.v2[0], this.v2[1]);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.clip();
    this.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    this.ctx.restore();
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Main code for this is from [here](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/raltF) but I want glassbreak like this using CSS

Comment: Converted your code block into a snippet as it makes it easier to read than a whole big code block of CSS + JS + HTML. Your problem description is incomplete but judging by the fact that the snippet doesn't execute as in the linked Pen, I think you are asking why it is not working on the whole. If this is indeed the question then please have a look at the External JS files linked in that Pen (click on the gear icon in the JS tab header).

Comment: can we make glass break effect with css or with javascript i want to  make a logo with text with glassbreak  my header color is light blue it should match

Comment: You have to try first. Ask for help if you get stuck anywhere and indicate what exactly is the problem you need help on. If you are looking for somebody to program the whole thing, then I am afraid the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

So while I don't have a specific example of glass breaking with CSS3, I do recommend this kind of effect would probably work very well with glass breaking:

http://www.species-in-pieces.com/

As you notice they use CSS3 polygons to render out shapes of animals. Here's an example snip from the site:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(44.65% 39.571%, 35.85% 59.429%, 52.85% 50.857%);
-webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
-moz-transition-duration: .8s;
 transition-duration: .8s;
```

Essentially you'd define webkit transforms through each defined polygon for the effect. Drawbacks of using a feature like this is it's currently only supported in webkit browsers, but at the same time that kind of animation affect would be pretty hard to do cross browser support for in CSS.

If I have some time I'll come around and do a quick glass breaking fiddle tomorrow

Comment: it's nice  can we make glass break effect with css or with javascript i want to  make a logo with text with glassbreak  my header color is light blue it should match